# php ceate booking timeslots from start and end time

Tags: php

I have start time (opening time) like 09:00 hour and end time (close time) 23:00 hour. Also, I have time slot like 45 minutes. Now I want to calculate all available time slots in array like:

```
array(
  [0]=>'09:45', 
  [1]=>'10:30', 
  [2]=>'11:15', 
  [3]=>'12:00', 
  [4]=>'12:45', 
  [5]=>'13:30', 
  .. )
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Help with what? I don't see a question there. This site is for programming questions, not someplace to dump you 'todo' list.

Comment: I assume 45:00 min is 00:45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution to that:

```
<?php 
$start = '09:00:00';
$end = '23:00:00';
$intrvl =  strtotime("1970-01-01 00:35:00 UTC");

$dateTimes = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($start),
    new DateInterval('PT'.$intrvl.'S'),
    new DateTime($end)
);
foreach ($dateTimes as $dt) {
  echo $dt->format('H:i'), "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array();
for($i = 900; $i <= 2300; $i += 45) {
    var_dump($i);
    $array[] = $i;
}
```

A for loop like this?